# Default WooCommerce sign in form won't allow users to type in the field

Tags: authentication, woocommerce

I have an WooCommerce website where the default Sign In form won't allow users to type their username or password in the text field. I have searched for many different solutions, but none of them seem to work.

I have tried clearning the CloudFlare cache, browser cache, making sure the URL of My Account page is correct, deleted HTACCESS and resaved Permalinks.

The URL is https://www.bounceonline.co.za/my-account/

Comment: can't tell anything from the description. what's the url? did you see any errors in the browser's console log?

Comment: @FaizAzhar I've updated the description to include the link.

Comment: disabling `form-group` class with `float: right` attribute in the `div` element brought the cursor back. seems like you're using Flipmart theme. i suggest submitting a support ticket on their forum https://ckthemes.ticksy.com for further advice from the author.

Comment: I have tested the same and it seems to work, thank you.